# Show data from sql query in template

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-templates

I have a website on which I'm showing news from other site, which are downloaded straight from database. So as a result in my view I have following list :

`news = ((title, text,date, image), (title, text, date, image), (title, text, date, image)).`

How I can show it in follwoing template :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>title</span>
            <img src="image" />
            <span>text</span>
            <span>date</date>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I thought about creating list of dictionaries and then checking {% ifequal key 'key' %} but still I would have to do a for loop for each key. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly your question or why you would have to do a for loop for each key if you used dictionary format.

If your news is always in the format you specified: `(title, text, date, image)`, set up your template like so:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in news %}
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>{{ item.0 }}</span> <!-- title -->
            <img src="{{ item.3 }}" /> <!-- image -->
            <span>{{ item.1 }}</span> <!-- text -->
            <span>{{ item.2 }}</span> <!-- date -->
        </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Although dictionaries are certainly nice for readability.. `{{ item.text }}` is better than `{{ item.1 }}`